# Fetch result set from a postgres Stored procedure in java

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I created a postgres function which returns a set of ref cursors. When I call the stored procedure from java the JDBC statement build is

```
select * from ga_rpt_movement('CODE','2018-5-10','2018-5-10','2018-5-10','C','STAT1','2018-5-10','2018-5-10','12344','A','T','34',25,50,'M','1','firstname',0,10) as result
```

When I run the same query on postgres terminal it gives me the four coursors.
Now I am not able to understand how do I fetch this cursor data in java.
Any suggestions, ideas are welcome and appreciated.

Result set when I run this query on postgres terminal look like this :

p_cr_personstatus

p_cr_identification

p_cr_phone

p_cr_count

(4 rows)

**I am trying to implement this using spring JPA only.**

Comment: I don't think an obfuscation layer like JPA will be able to properly handle a ResultSet that contains ref cursors. This is very easy in plain JDBC though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so do you suggest that using plain JDBC will allow me to register more than one ref cursor as output param because earlier (Using JPA )when I was trying to register more than one cursor, I got an exception "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: PostgreSQL supports only one REF_CURSOR parameter, but multiple were registered".

Comment: I don't use JPA, so I can't comment on that. But there is no need to "register" anything. You just run the select using `executeQuery()`. The `ResultSet` will then contain one row for each ref cursor. Each ref cursor can be processed as a `ResultSet`

Comment: If I dont register out param as ref cursor the it throws "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: No function outputs were registered."

Comment: Again: for a simple `executeQuery()` you do not need to register an out parameter at all. It sounds as if you are using a `CallableStatement` rather than a plain `Statement.executeQuery()`. You can process the result using something like this: http://dpaste.com/2CC4Z8X

Comment: Yes. I am able to fetch the resultset, thanks for that ..!! But when I process it using  while(rs.next()) { } it skips the last row of the result set. Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name how do we call multiple stored procedures in parallel and process the result sets once ?